# How to have Haddock generate docs with my suffix handler?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a suffix handler to hack some source during build. It works fine and generates correct result.

But when I ran `stack haddock`, it generated docs against original source. Checking out the .hs in .stack-work/ folder, my handler was not involved.

So I checked the UserHook arg passed to haddockHook, it seemed containing my handler. So I am confused. What should I do?

PS: My Setup.hs

```
main =
  defaultMainWithHooks simpleUserHooks
    { hookedPreProcessors = [ ("hs", \bi lbi clbi ->
        PreProcessor False $ \(iD, iF) (oD, oF) verbosity -> myHandler) ]}
```